# Sed regex, extracting part of a string in Mac terminal

Tags: macos, sed

I have sample data like "(stuff/thing)" and I'm trying to extract "thing".

I'm doing this in the terminal on OSX and I can't quite seem to get this right.

Here's the last broken attempt

```
echo '(stuff/thing)' | sed -n 's/\((.*)\)/\1/p'
```

Comment: Two quick hints: since you're _not_ using `-E`, you must use _basic_ regexes (BREs), where, counter-intuitively, parentheses must be _escaped_ to be special - you have it the other way around.
The main problem is that in order to _output_ only _part_ of the line, you must _match_ ALL of it, and replace it with the part of interest. With a BRE, that would be
`echo '(stuff/thing)' | sed -n 's/^.*\/\(.*\))$/\1/p'`; with a ERE (extended regex), this would be: `echo '(stuff/thing)' | sed -En 's/^.*\/(.*)\)$/\1/p'`

Comment: P.S.: Both commands would work the same with _GNU_ `sed` (but note that the `-E` option to activate EREs is an alias there for the better-known `-r`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would say:

```
$ echo '(stuff/thing)' | sed -n 's@.*/\([^)]*\))@\1@p'
thing
```

I start saying:

```
$ echo '(stuff/thing)' | sed -n 's@.*/@@p'
thing)
```

Note I use `@` as sed delimiter for better readability.

Then, I want to get rid of what comes from the `)`. For this, we have to capture the block with `\([^)]*\))` and print it back with `\1`.

So all together this is doing:

```bash
#                print the captured group
#                ^^
#                | 
   .*/\([^)]*\))@\1
#  ^^^| ^^^^^ |
#   | | ------|---- all but )
#   | |       |
#   | ^^     ^^
#   | capture group
#   |
#  everything up to a /
```

Answer (score 4):

To provide an **`awk` alternative** to [fedorqui's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33424782/45375):

`awk` makes it easy to parse lines into fields based on separators:

```
$ echo '(stuff/thing)' | awk -F'[()/]' '{print $3}'
thing
```

- `-F[()/]` specifies that any of the characters `(` `)` `/` should serve as a field separator when breaking each input line into fields.
- `$3` refers to the 3rd field (`thing` is the *3rd* field, because the line *starts* with a field separator, which implies that field 1 (`$1`) is the *empty* string *before* it).

---

As for **why your `sed` command didn't work**:

Since you're *not* using `-E`, you must use *basic* regexes (BREs), where, counter-intuitively, parentheses must be *escaped* to be special - you have it the other way around.

The main problem, however, is that in order to *output* only *part* of the line, you must *match* ALL of it, and replace it with the part of interest.

With a **BRE**, that would be:

```
echo '(stuff/thing)' | sed -n 's/^.*\/\(.*\))$/\1/p'
```

With an **ERE** (extended regex), it would be:

```
echo '(stuff/thing)' | sed -En 's/^.*\/(.*)\)$/\1/p'`
```

Also note that both commands work as-is with *GNU* `sed`, so the problem is not Mac-specific (but note that the `-E` option to activate EREs is an alias there for the better-known `-r`).
That said, regex *dialects* do differ across implementations; *GNU* `sed` generally supports *extensions* to the POSIX-mandated BREs and EREs.

Comment: +1 for the answer (which may be fragile if the input consists in more than just `(stuff/thing)`) and explanation. And also thanks for improving my answer

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in 2 easy parts - remove everything up to and including the slash and then everything from the closing parenthesis onwards:

```
echo '(stuff/thing)' | sed -e 's/.*\///' -e 's/).*//'
```

Comment: Good! Note that using another delimiter may improve the readability